# Importing interactive Mathematica plots into a website

Tags: export

I'm new to Mathematica, I've been using the free version of wolframscript and the manipulate function to generate interactable ComplexPlot graphs, I was wondering whether I could embed these graphs into a website using either HTML or javascript, whilst keeping the ability to interact with them, without having to pay for the licence. Does anyone have any advice?

Comment: Take a look at this one. The project is currently under active development and there will be many examples and features in the future
https://github.com/jerryI/wolfram-js-frontend

Comment: and look at this https://github.com/JerryI/wljs-graphics-d3 
https://jerryi.github.io/wljs-docs/docs/frontend/Tutorial/Dynamics

Answer (score 1):

> I could embed these graphs into a website using either HTML or
> javascript, whilst keeping the ability to interact with them

Not on the web page. You can't interact with it. You could put a movie ofcourse or gif file animation but no interaction.

long time ago, there was the ability to run Manipulate directly inside web page. But this is no longer possible as all browsers now stopped this feature. (NPAPI is no longer supported due to security).

[Why does Wolfram Research no longer support the CDF plugin?](https://support.wolfram.com/20057?)

> Wolfram Research no longer releases or supports browser plugins for
> Wolfram Player because major browsers have stopped supporting NPAPI
> plugins.
>
> We instead recommend the Wolfram Cloud for deploying Wolfram CDF
> documents on the web.
>
> We also recommend viewing CDF files offline using the Wolfram Player.
> If the CDF document you are trying to view is not downloadable, please
> contact the according author for access.

So to have users run Manipulate CDF in your web site, they have to download the file and install the player, then they can run it locally. Installation of the player is a one time task. After that, they just have to download the CDF file.

https://www.wolfram.com/player/

Btw, this is what I do for all my CDF's [here](https://12000.org/my_notes/mma_demos/index.htm) you can add a link to your web page telling users where to download the player to make it easier for them.

There was a rumor long time ago that WRI will have tool to convert Manipulate to Javascript so it can run directly inside the browser. Do not think this will ever happen.

Another option to interact with your Manipulate is to put it inside a PDF file and use Latex animate package.  See [Mathematica animation into PDF using latex](https://12000.org/my_notes/Mathematica_animation_into_PDF_using_latex/index.htm)

Users can now just download the PDF and open it locally using say Adobe PDF reader and then interact with your manipulate inside the PDF. But this is limited in scope. Note this only works if they download the PDF. As the browser builtin PDF viewers do not support the animate package. At least last time I checked.